# jQuery autocomplete allow arrow keys for empty textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a textfield with autocomplete. I want to be able to user the arrow keys even if the user haven't entered any character yet.

Is this achievable?

Comment: have you tried anythink so far..and can you share a little code and maybe a fiddle

Comment: you want a user to type with arrow keys aur not it sounds confusing

Comment: See Jerremimiahs answer, he's correct. Maybe you'll understand, what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting minlength to 0

`$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 0 });`

See also:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength